# No longer able to mirror objects

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

I'm still fairly new to blender and the last few days I had been following sculpting tutorials and was able to mirror objects with no problem. But today when I was trying to mirror them it is not working. I also get this pop in the bottom saying "failed to set value". I tried to look up how to fix this but did not get the answer I was looking for and I have even updated
to the latest version and I still cannot get the mirroring to work anymore. Any suggestions on figuring this out would be awesome.
Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Try changing the mirror axis, as right now you're mirroring along the axis pointing towards the camera: https://i.imgur.com/XhqYpx0.png other than that, test if the mirror modifier also doesn't work in a new file. If it works there, you can upload a file where it doesn't work, using this website: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and resources! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is showing $Y$ and $Z$ axis (Green and Blue lines across the screen respectively), but the modifier is set to mirror only on $X$, which would be perpendicular to this view, therefore impossible to see.

You can add mirror in $Y$ on the modifier.

[image]

[image]

It helps if you use a different view, that clearly shows the axis you  want to work on (like top view)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a great deal. I also figured out something I had accidentally messed with in the transform / relations tab. But now I am good to go. You are amazing!!!